# Integer division in Java

Tags: java, math, int, division

This feels like a stupid question, but I can't find the answer anywhere in the Java documentation. If I declare two ints and then divide them, what exactly is happening? Are they converted to `floats/doubles` first, divided, then cast back to an `integer`, or is the division "done" as integers?

Also, purely from experimentation, integer division seems to round the answer towards zero (i.e. `3/2 = 1` and `-3/2 = -1`). Am I right in believing this?

Comment: No conversion occurs. They are divided as ints. And `-3/2 == -1`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.2

Comment: the simple way of thinking about it is they are divided, and anything less than a full int is truncated.

Comment: @AndyTurner  "-3/2 = 1" was a silly typo on my part, sorry!

Comment: Int division in a computer basically is very similar to how you would do long division with paper and pencil to get a quotient and a remainder.  The main difference is, the computer does it in base 2 instead of base 10.  When you divide with '/', the result is the quotient, and the remainder is thrown away.  When you divide with '%', you get the remainder, and the quotient is thrown away.

Comment: @Keiwan Not floor division.  "Floor" means round downwards -  but Java division is always towards zero.  For negative numbers, this is the opposite of floor division.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, I shouldn't have called it floor division since this was a Java question. It seems like I got a little confused because "integer division" is the same as floor division in some other programming languages (Python, Wolfram Language...). But if I'm allowed to nitpick a little bit: You say "Floor means round downwards" but technically in Java rounding [DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#enum.constant.summary) means towards zero and UP is away from zero :)

Comment: Yeah, it's misnamed in Java.  I meant "down" in a mathematical sense.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

They are being divided in integer arithmetics. So dividing integer `a` by integer `b` you get how many times `b` fits into `a`. Also `a % b` will give you a remainder of a division. So `(a / b ) * b + a % b = a`

Answer (score 15):

Java does autoconvert types:

"It autoconverts ints to doubles. It autoconverts shorts and bytes to ints even when no ints are involved, requiring constant annoying casts when you want to do short or byte arithmetic. It autoconverts primitives to wrappers and vice versa for boxing and autoboxing." - [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795248/integer-division-in-java/37795368?noredirect=1#comment63057079_37795368)

<s>Java **never** casts anything without you specifying it.</s>

But still `integer / integer = integer`.

Also, it does always truncate the result. So if the result would be 0.999999 as float the integer division would still return 0.

Comment: No, it always rounds *towards zero*.

Comment: I meant that, sorry

Comment: I believe you meant truncate

Comment: "Java never casts anything without you specifying it" - it totally does. It autoconverts ints to doubles. It autoconverts shorts and bytes to ints even when no ints are involved, requiring constant annoying casts when you want to do short or byte arithmetic. It autoconverts primitives to wrappers and vice versa for boxing and autoboxing.

Comment: "It autoconverts ints to doubles" please provide an example.

Comment: Example:  double x = 15.9d / 4;

Comment: To add another counterexample to "Java never casts anything without you specifying it": Java even performs *narrowing conversions* without an explicit cast in certain constructs. `long v = 0; v += 3.14;` No error, not even a warning.

Comment: @OneCricketter - "I believe you meant truncate" - The JLS uses these words: *"Integer division rounds toward 0."*.  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2).  That *means the same thing* as truncation ... but what Andy wrote is correct.