# Big Error in Java or incongruency with simple operators

Tags: java

I'm beginning in Java, and could anyone explain me why Java gives me these answers?

I have a very simple class trying to learn how to round a number. 
I want 2 decimals
so...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double pi1 = Math.PI;
    System.out.println("pi1 = " + pi1);
    double p2 ;

    p2= Math.round(pi1*100)/100;

    //p2= Math.round(pi1*100)
    //p2=p2/100;

    System.out.println("p2 = " + p2);

}
```

If I run this result is:

> p2 = 3.0

Then I change

```
    //p2= Math.round(pi1*100)/100;

    p2 = Math.round(pi1*100);
    p2 = p2/100;
```

Now, result is:

> p2 = 3.14

as I wanted

Why with these differences? Why the first option doesn't give me 3.14
I think that I've made a correct code with 1st option.

Please, anyone could tell me why?
These things makes me don't trust Java.

Thank you.

Comment: I know this might not directly solve your problem, but if you haven't yet, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795248/integer-division-in-java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No mistake here, it works properly. Method `Math.round(double)` returns type long.

- In your first variant, you receive result long 314 and divide it by 100 and get the result 3, and then assign it back to double.
- In your second variant, you receive long result 314 and assign it back to double. Dividing double keeps precision as opposed to dividing long, so you get the correct result of 3.14

There for make `p2= Math.round(pi1*100)/100;` as

```
p2= Math.round(pi1*100) / 100.0;
```

**Output -:**

```
pi1 = 3.141592653589793
p2 = 3.14
```

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that you know how [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0) works in Java. In short, when both sides of `/` are integral types, like in `314 / 100`, the expression evaluates to an integer too, like `3`.

[`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-) returns a `long`, which is an integral type. In your first code, you have the expression `Math.round(pi1*100)/100`. `Math.round(...)` returns an integer type, `100` is an integer literal, so integer division occurs.

However, in the second code, you first assigned the result of `Math.round` to `p2`. The `long` returned is implicitly converted to a `double` first, and stored in `p2`. You then wrote an expression in `p2`: `p2/100`. Here, one of the operands is `double`, so integer division does not occur.

Therefore, the one liner version that is the same as the second code is:

```
p2 = ((double)Math.round(pi1*100))/100;
```

You don't see the `double` conversion in the second code because it is done implicitly.

**A note on rounding**

This way rounding doubles should be used if you want to do calculations with the rounded number afterwards. If you just want to display a rounded number as output, you should use `String.format`, `System.out.printf`, or `DecimalFormat`. Read more about these methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java).

Comment: Thak you very much. I assumed that as I have declared p2 as double, the result, if posible, should be double.

Comment: @Fer Yeah, I can see where you could have misunderstood, but Java doesn't infer what you want based on the variable you are assigning to.

Comment: Thanks again, and I tried with another option and works
p2 = Math.round(pi1*100)/100.0;
So, if I want double numbers, I have to use at least one double number