# Float/Double doesn't seem to be working. The result keeps coming out to be an integer

Tags: java, floating-point, double

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        final double PI = Math.PI;
        final double sphereVolumeConstant = (4/3);
        
        System.out.println("Volume of a sphere.");
        
        System.out.print("Radius of sphere: ");
        double radius = userInput.nextDouble();
        
        double volumeOfSphere = sphereVolumeConstant * PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
        
        System.out.println("Volume = " + sphereVolumeConstant);
    }

}
```

Terminal:

> Volume of a sphere.
> Radius of sphere: 5
> Volume = 1.0

I am trying to calculate the constant itself which keeps coming out to be an integer even though it shouldn't, or at least I don't think it should. Can someone please help/explain?

Comment: What gives `(4/3)`?

Comment: 1.3 repeating. But it's not outputting that which is confusing because I made it a double.

Comment: Compare:  (double) (4/3)  with  (double) (4.0/3). Integer division produces an integer. 4.0 / 3 is a double divided by an integer which produces a double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sphereVolumeConstant` will always be `1.0`. writing `double` before variable doesn't make every operation on it double. If You want to make `sphereVolumeConstant` to be equal to `1.(3)` You have to write:

```
final double sphereVolumeConstant = (4.0/3);
```

Or:

```
final double sphereVolumeConstant = ((double) 4 / 3);
```

Now the operation will be made in double because `4.0` or `(double) 4` is double.

Answer (score 2):

Because the value of `sphereVolumeConstant` is assigned as `(4/3)`, its value will always be `1.0` because of how integer division works. What you need to do is cast at least the `4` or the `3` to a double/float:

1. `final double sphereVolumeConstant = ((double)4/3);`
2. `final double sphereVolumeConstant = (4/(double)3);`
3. `final double sphereVolumeConstant = (4.0/3);`
4. `final double sphereVolumeConstant = (4/3.0);`

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37795248/integer-division-in-java) explains why integer division behaves in this way.

Answer (score 1):

## Default is `int` for your dividend & divisor

In your example `( 4 / 3 )`, the 4 and the 3 (your dividend & divisor) both default to being integers. So you are dividing one integer by another. You get a resulting integer as your quotient.

```
System.out.println( 4 / 3 ) ;
```

> 1

Then you cast that resulting integer to be a `double`, `1.0`.

```
double a = ( 4 / 3 )
```

> 1.0

If you mean `4` or `3` to be floating-point numbers, say so. Mark them with a `d` for `double` or `f` for float.

```
( 4d / 3d )
```

> 1.3333333333333333

Or use [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator).

```
( 4.0 / 3.0 )
```

> 1.3333333333333333

### `BigDecimal`

If you care about accuracy rather than speed-of-execution, use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). Never use `float`/`Float` or `double`/`Double` for money or other matters demanding accuracy.

Pass a `MathContext` containing precision (total number of digits) and [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

```java
MathContext mc = new MathContext( 7 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN ) ;  // Banker's rounding.
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal( "4" ).divide( new BigDecimal( "3" ) , mc ) ;
```

> 1.333333

Alternatively, pass scale (number of digits to the right of the decimal separator) and [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html).

```java
BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal( "4" ).divide( new BigDecimal( "3" ) , 2 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN ) ;
```

> 1.33

### Example code

See all that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/VOA8pd).