# Palindrome Java vs JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java

Why does this work in Java but not in JavaScript? I tried using this in Java and its working perfectly fine but I can't figure out why it's only printing "Not a palindrome" in JavaScript? thank you

```
 var n = 121;
 var sum = 0, r;
 var temp = n;    
 while(n>0)
   {    
    r = n % 10;   
    sum = (sum*10)+r;    
    n = n/10;    
   }    
  if(temp==sum)    
    console.log("It is a Palindrome number.");
  else  
    console.log("Not a palindrome");
```

Comment: It's different because java has no relationship to javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using floating point division when you want floor division(aka integer division), since JS numbers are always floating point. To fix it, use Math.floor after the division:

```
var n = 121;
var sum = 0
var r;
var temp = n;    
while(n > 0){    
    r = n % 10;   
    sum = (sum * 10) + r;    
    n = Math.floor(n / 10);    
}
if(temp == sum){
    console.log("It is a palindrome number.");
}else{
    console.log("Not a palindrome");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason this code does not same exact results in both java and javascript is because of difference in data types.

You are (most likely) declaring vars in java like:

```
int n = 121;    // this is strictly an integer
```

Whereas when you declare in javascript:

```
var n = 121;    // this is interpreted according to the calculation where used
```

So in java, n/10 will give you an integer, a round value **integer** answer.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37795340/7892830

But in javascript, n/10 may give you a **decimal** value. Which is where your program is failing.

***Solution*:**
*Use proper `Math.ceil()` or `floor()` function in javascript so it gets rounded to the nearest integer value. I'll let you figure out which one you need in this case.*